# Failed to load resource when loading image

Tags: android, android-glide, image-loading

I am making a project for image loading but whenever I try to load an image into circle image view through glide but whenever I run the app, the image view goes blank and error comes up from glide.

```
dp = view.findViewById(R.id.circleView);

GlideApp
    .with(getActivity())
    .load(serverResponse.getMessage().getPic())//C:/Apache24/htdocs/app2/User Files/User Id-102/User id 102.jpg
    .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
            // log exception
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error loading image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.v("glide", "Error loading image", e);
            return false; // important to return false so the error placeholder can be placed
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
        return false;
    }
})
.into(dp);
```

Log

> **2018-11-02 19:20:08.709** 31664-31664/com.example.user.myapplication W/Glide: Load failed for C:/Apache24/htdocs/app2/User Files/User Id-102/User id 102.jpg with size [200x200]
>   class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
>   **2018-11-02 19:20:08.718** 31664-31664/com.example.user.myapplication V/glide: Error loading image
>   class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource

I cannot figure out actually from where the error is occurring.

Comment: Can you give the url for the image.

Comment: C:/Apache24/htdocs/app2/User Files/User Id-102/User id 102.jpg

Comment: are you trying to use Glide against some java projects? your image reference is not valid one, it seems to be a desktop resource path.

Comment: Yeah, i want to load image from localhost

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, I wanted to load file from the localhost server of my pc and I was using pc file system reference which glide does not support but when I passed the IP address along with the file address (e.g. `http://(your ip like 192....)/your localhost project folder/image.jpg`) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're using an invalid image reference. Glide can load resources from the internet (http or https) or from the device's (mobile/tablet) file system. But it seems your response contains a reference to an image file on your PC's file system.

Comment: So, what should i do now ? I want to load image from my localhost in my device

Comment: I think you will not be able to load the image until your server runs on your localhost. You have to publish these images somewhere on the global network (e.g. us AWS). 
Theoretically you can setup some shared folder(on your local PC) for your local network, and put some images there, and try to load an image with Glide by the following way: https://127.0.0.1:{port}/{shared_folder}/{image}.{extension}
But it's really theoretically. I'm not really sure how to setup such a thing correctly, that's why i prefer to dont waste your time, and upload your images to AWS